# Exclude specific tags (by id) from the_tags

Tags: tags

Within a single post I show all tags of the specific post by using this:

```
the_tags( $tags_opening, ' ', $tags_ending );
```

But sometimes I mark a post with a tag that should not appear on that single page (but this tag shall still be found on - for example - an overview page with all tags).

How can I exclude specific tags by ID from this list of tags within the post (and just on the single page)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that this is the best decision, but you can use the filter to cut your special tag without modifying templates.

```
add_filter('the_tags', 'wpse_320497_the_tags');

function wpse_320497_the_tags($tags) {
    $exclude_tag = 'word';

    // You can add your own conditions here
    // For example, exclude specific tag only for posts or custom taxonomy
    if(!is_admin() && is_singular()) {
        $tags = preg_replace("~,\s+<a[^>]+>{$exclude_tag}</a>~is", "", $tags);
    }

    return $tags;
});
```

If you confused with regexp, you can rewrite it with `explode` and `strpos` functions.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) to get the terms of the `post_tag` taxonomy according to your needs. It offers parameters to achieve this, especially `exclude` or `exclude_tree`. All available parameters are documented at [`WP_Term_Query::__construct()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#parameters).

Then you basically recreate what `the_tags()` does in a custom function. To elaborate a bit, `the_tags()` calls [`get_the_tag_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tag_list/) which calls [`get_the_term_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/). If you take a look at the documentation, source code you can easily create the same markup.

Generally speaking it might be worth considering a different approach, for example using a custom taxonomy to collect those terms you want to show on overview pages but not on single pages.